# Change Password to RODC Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am creating a webpart in which I am writing a code to change active directory password of the current context user but I am getting this error:

> Password couldn't be changed due to restrictions: Configuration
>   information could not be read from the domain controller, either
>   because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070547)

I am using `AccountManagement` namespace, used `PrincipalContext`/`UserPrincipal` and it gets successfully connected to the Active Directory but when I call its ChangePassword Method it errors out.

The administrator has said that the Active Directory is READ ONLY, let me know how can I change the active directory password with RODC (Read-Only Domain Controller)

Thanks

Comment: are you connecting to the domain or to a specific ad controller when creating the PrincipalContext? Usually the classes in the AccountManagement namespace should ignore RO domain controllers just because they can't be used to actually manage accounts. So if you connect to the domain (instead of a specific server), you should automatically connect to the nearest standard domain controller.

Comment: Yes, I have debugged the code and during the debug I can see that PrincipalContext object has a ConnectedServer name in it, which means it has connected successfully, it can also find the current user but when I call the method ChangePassword it breaks out to exception.

Comment: maybe this technet blog post helps: http://blogs.technet.com/b/fieldcoding/archive/2012/06/25/active-directory-service-interface-adsi-and-the-read-only-domain-controller-rodc-avoiding-performance-issues.aspx . It isn't directly connected to your question but it shows how to connect to a rwdc when the rodc has the highest quality rating.